# Finding Third Points of triangle using other two points with known distances

Tags: math, trigonometry

[image]

In the above image, I have three points `(x1,y1)`  `(x2,y2)`  `(x3,y3)`.

I know the values of `x1,y1` and `x2,y2` .I know the euclidean distances of `(x1,y1)->(x3,y3)`
and `(x2,y2)->(x3,y3)`. Having these information how can I find the `(x3,y3)`?

I expect anything like a code snippet or the logic will be useful...

I have tried to solve this using the circle equations but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ...and belongs here as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: The problem is math.stackexchange.com don't like answers written in Javascript, and using all of the maths symbols and lines makes answers much harder to understand for non-mathematicians. There needs to be somewhere for maths questions and javascript to co-exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can solve this using a bit of trigonometry:

Cosine theorem (phi is the inner angle at the first point):

```
d3^2 = d1^2 + d2^2 - 2 d1 d2 cos phi
cos phi = (d1^2 + d2^2 - d3^2) / (2 d1 d2)
```

For a given cosine, we can calculate the according sine:

```
cos^2 phi + sin^2 phi = 1
sin phi = +- sqrt(1 - cos^2 phi)
```

So there are two solutions for the angle at the first point. One positive and one negative.

We can use this angle to rotate the difference vector `diff1 = (x2 - x1, y2 - y1)` to point towards the third point:

```
P3 = P1 + d2/d1 * / cos phi * (x2 - x1) - sin phi * (y2 - y1))
                  \ sin phi * (x2 - x1) + cos phi * (y2 - y1))
```

There is no need to calculate the actual angle, because we just need its sine and cosine. Put both calculated values for the sine in and you get two possible points for P3.

Comment: Why do you use the phi constant? I mean, in the question doesn't give any angle

Comment: Phi is not used as a constant but as a measure derived from the variables in the question. Actually, only its sine and cosine are used.

Comment: Thanks, I understand cos phi and sin phi like variables, but I have questions, how to solve the expression P1 + (d2/d1 ...)? I mean P1 is a point (x, y) and the result of (d2/d1 * ...) is a number, sorry for be thorough :(

Comment: You use `d2/d1` as a factor for the last vector (shown in two rows). Multiply both components by the factor.

Comment: Finally I got it, thanks a lot bro :)