# How to get the third point coordinates in isosceles triangle?

Tags: math, geometry, computational-geometry, trigonometry

Isosceles triangle ABC
AB = AC = d_1
BC = d_2

```
A = (x_1, y_1)  
B = (x_2, y_2)  
C = (x_3, y_3)
```

Angle BAC = Φ
Angle ABC = Angle ACB = Θ

I want an equation for x_3 and y_3 (and I know there will be two values)
x_3 = ??
y_3 = ??

Comment: What values are given and what values are unknown? For general triangles, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970605/finding-third-points-of-triangle-using-other-two-points-with-known-distances/24980145#24980145) might help you.

Comment: @NicoSchertler  
Givens: x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2, d_1, d_2, Φ, Θ .  
Unknown: x_3, y_3 .  
Can you clarify this part in the mentioned link?
    P3 = P1 + d2/d1 * / cos phi * (x2 - x1) - sin phi * (y2 - y1))
                  \ sin phi * (x2 - x1) + cos phi * (y2 - y1))
. And what does " * / " mean?

Comment: That entire right part is a 2D vector. In your case it's even easier because phi is known and the difference vectors are of equal length (meaning `d2/d1=1`).

Comment: @NicoSchertler , I did the following: x_3 = x_1 + (Cos(Φ) * (x_2 - x_1) - Sin(Φ) * (y_2 - y_1)) .. y_3 = y_1 + (Cos(Φ) * (x_2 - x_1) + Sin(Φ) * (y_2 - y_1)) .. but the results was wrong, since AB wasn't equal to AC !

Comment: @DouglasZare , I can't rely on slope since it could cause a division by zero..

Comment: Obviously you should make special cases for things like that. But if you think it wasn't helpful I'll just delete it. It was far more steps than you should need to implement a solution.

Comment: You have an error in your formula. `y3` should be `sin(phi) * (x2 - x1) + cos(phi) * (y2 - y1)`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler
x3 = (Math.Cos(phi) * (y2 - y1)) - (Math.Sin(phi) * (x2 - x1)) ..
y3 = (Math.Sin(phi) * (x2 - x1)) + (Math.Cos(phi) * (y2 - y1)) ..
Result: 
https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/479x216q90/631/UnEVzB.jpg

Comment: Now your x calculation is wrong, which was correct before.

Comment: Two many input values... You can use only coordinates `(x1, y1)`, `(x2, y2)` and the angle Phi as input. Is it OK for you?

Comment: @NicoSchertler , x3 = x1 + (Math.Cos(phi) * (x2 - x1) - Math.Sin(phi) * (y2 - y1)) .. y3 = (Math.Sin(phi) * (x2 - x1)) + (Math.Cos(phi) * (y2 - y1)) .. result 1: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/427x284q90/673/lNTCs8.jpg .. result 2: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/378x299q90/745/iPJKFK.jpg .. result 3: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/469x256q90/910/msT2od.jpg .. The highlighted line is AB, the black areas are where C should be nearly located

Comment: @HEKTO , Sure it is OK! do you have a solution?

Comment: The problem can be reduced to a system of two quadratic equations - it's solvable, but algebraic manipulations are long and complex. I can explain the reduction process, but these manipulations will be left for you

Comment: @HEKTO , OK this is acceptable. waiting for you to explain the reduction process..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve this. The solution key was the conversion between the [Cartesian Coordinate System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) and the [Polar Coordinate System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system).

```
x_3 = AB * Cos(Φ) + x_1
y_3 = AB * Sin(Φ) + y_1
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to find an intersection point of the axis of symmetry of the triangle and its `BC` side - let's denote this point `D` and its coordinates `(x, y)`. Then you'll have two vectors:

```
AD = (x - x1, y - y1)
BD = (x - x2, y - y2)
```

These vectors should satisfy two conditions. The condition #1 is `AD` and `BD` orthogonality, which can be expressed as their dot product equality to zero:

```
(x - x1) * (x - x2) + (y - y1) * (y - y2) = 0
```

For the condition #2 you can use the angle Phi or the length of the `BC` side - it's up to you, it looks like you have some flexibility in input data. The condition with the angle says that the tangent of half-angle Phi is equal to the length of the vector `BD` divided by the length of the vector `AD`:

```
sqrt((x - x2)^2 + (y - y2)^2) / sqrt((x - x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2) = tan(Phi / 2)
```

If you know the `BC` length in advance, the condition #2 will be simpler - it just says that the length of the vector `BD` is equal to the `d2` divided by two:

```
sqrt((x - x2)^2 + (y - y2)^2) = d2 / 2
```

So, you'll get a system of two quadratic equations with variables `x` and `y`. It's difficult to solve such an system in general case, but this case is a little bit simpler because you don't have cross products `x` and `y` there.

After you calculate the point `D` the third vertex (`C`) of the triangle can be found using the vector equation:

```
C = B + 2 * BD
```

Comment: Check your formulas with simple cases at first, for example - `x1 = y1 = 0`, `x2 = y2 = 1` and `Phi = 90 grades`