# Finding the unknown third point

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

As provided in the image i know co-ordinates of two points `A(x1, y1)` and `C(x2, y2)`, and also i have distance `D` from `C` to third point i.e `B(x, y)` and the angle `thetha` made by three points. Here `thetha` can range from 0 to 360.

Please i need the know third point from the following data given, any code would be helpful.

As i have tried the possible way using the method provided in the following link i was not able to find correct result

[Javascript function to find third point of triangle when all sides, angles and first two points are known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277245/javascript-function-to-find-third-point-of-triangle-when-all-sides-angles-and-f)

**PS.**

Vectorial answers is cool, but I use javascript and don't know how to add vectors over there.

[image: Find unknown point]

Comment: Why is this tagged with `javascript`? That's a math problem/homework...

Comment: this looks like math and not coding?

Comment: i need it in javascript to solve my problem, @Andreas, updated the tags

Comment: That's still just a geometry/math problem and therefor off-topic for SO.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: D is the hypotenuse of a right triangle. The angle is 180 - theta.

Comment: @MattEllen, the angle varies from 0 to 360, so it is not a right angled triangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CA_unit[0] = (A[0] - C[0]);
CA_unit[1] = (A[1] - C[1]);

norm_CA = sqrt( CA_unit[0] * CA_unit[0] + CA_unit[1] * CA_unit[1] );

CA_unit[0] = CA_unit[0] / norm_CA;
CA_unit[1] = CA_unit[1] / norm_CA;

cs = cos(theta);
sn = sin(theta);

// point after clockwise rotation:
B[0] = D*(  cs * CA_unit[0] + sn*CA_unit[1]) + C[0];
B[1] = D*(- sn * CA_unit[0] + cs*CA_unit[1]) + C[1];

// alternative point, counter clockwise rotation:
B_[0] = D*( cs * CA_unit[0] - sn*CA_unit[1]) + C[0];
B_[1] = D*( sn * CA_unit[0] + cs*CA_unit[1]) + C[1];
```

Comment: are you considering the distance D here

Comment: thank you, works as expected, also can you find a alternative point if possible like
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277245/javascript-function-to-find-third-point-of-triangle-when-all-sides-angles-and-f

Comment: can you confirm this, is theta used here is in radians

Comment: @paradox In general, theta is in radians, because I suspect cos and sin use radians in . However, if you have cos and sin that use theta as degrees, the formulas are the same, no difference. If your theta is in degrees, then you can switch to radians by theta * pi/180.

Comment: @paradox I added a second point, counter-clock wise oriented, not like on your picture .